# Laravel загрузка проекта на сервер

Tags: laravel

[image: Изображение]
Почему появляется ошибка 500? Уже меня и файл htaccess,всеравно не помогает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего ошибка 500 из-за того, что веб сервер не имеет права на запись в папку `storage`. Почитайте лог Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Поставил права,теперь ошибка 403

Comment: @quaresma89 403 теперь нужно htaccess поменять отредактировал ответ

Comment: Всеравно 403 ошибка. Это надо в htaccess  в корне ставить? или в папке public?

Comment: @quaresma89 в папке public и ваш `apache` должен быть настроет как 
`document_root path/public`

Answer (score -1):

Дай права `777` вместо `755` на папку `storage` и должно все работать